# Porque essa tag HTML não mostra o link, só quando eu tiro o style="display: none;"

Tags: html

Estou fazendo um tour no minha área administrativa, mas ela não funciona quando eu mando para o servidor. No projeto do rapaz no GIT no site onde eu fiz o download funciona perfeitamente

A tag é essa:

```
<a href="#" id="tour" style="display: none;" >Tutorial</a>
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOPT. Este site não é um fórum. Faça o [tour] e leia [ask]. Depois clique em [edit] para melhorar a sua pergunta e deixar a sua dificuldade mais clara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display: none; é o ocultador do css a propriedade style é só para adicionar o estilo direto no elemento

Comment: E como eu resolveria isso ?

Comment: Na verdade não entendi seu problema, mas para tornar o elemento visível basta substituir o "none" pelo "block" ou remover essa tag.

Comment: Queria fazer isso aqui man
http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Easy-Interactive-Visual-Tour-Plugin-For-jQuery-mytour.html

Comment: Já tentou usar o código abaixo do exemplo, display none em um link não faz sentido, a não ser q ele esteja no elemento que vai aparecer, como eu vi no exemplo, ai é preciso o display none para o efeito inicial, porém no seu caso creio q o problema seja outro.

Comment: Natan Melo, mas lá na parte How to use, não tem esse display: none;

Answer (score 1):

A função do `display: none` simplesmente esconde o elemento em questão. O próprio nome já fala "none" (nada, nenhum).

Pode colocar `display: block`, para resolver ou simplesmente tirar esse estilo.

```
<a href="#" id="tour" style="display: block;" >Tutorial</a>
```

ou

```
<a href="#" id="tour">Tutorial</a>
```